# Develop RPi framebuffer program on Linux laptop

Tags: camera, linux, framebuffer

Is there any emulator or some other way to develop a program for my 320x480 Adafruit PiTFT screen (available as `/dev/fb1`) on my Linux Mint laptop?

The program currently gets images from Pi Camera, does some processing and displays the image with some info on the PiTFT, however to work on it I have to physically sit by the Pi to see the output. I would like to work on the processing part even when I'm away, using my laptop webcam and some frambuffer emulator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Debian Stretch with Raspberry Pi Desktop for PC and Mac](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/). I don't know if it fit your needs, in particular accessing the hardware and framebuffer but I think it is worth to have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that only gives me ready access to the main screen (like HDMI on real RPi). It doesn't help much with a direct *framebuffer access*. Or am I missing something?